# Transfer Microsoft Access like statement to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, sql-like

The original query is for an ms-access db table and contains a like statement which I can not run on the same table transfered to postgresql.

The sql statement:

```
SELECT Table1.property1, Table1.property2
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE (((Table2.NAME) Like "*" & [Table1]![property2] & "*"));
```

`property2` is the name of the column. How can I keep the same logic and transfer the sql statement so it works with postgresql?

Comment: That won't run on Oracle.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe You're absolutly right, I'm sry. The query is run on an ms-access table which is imported from an oracle db source. I updated the question.

Comment: What do `[Table1]![property2]` and `LIKE "*"` mean in Access? Is this supposed to be a cross join?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe LIKE and * are wildcard searches. SELECT * FROM .. WHERE Name LIKE '*Lauren*' will return your name.

Comment: I understand what `LIKE 'Lauren'` does, but `LIKE "*"` does not make sense to me.

Comment: I am not MS Access fun but I suppose that it is equal to `SELECT Table1.property1, Table1.property2 FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON (Table2.NAME Like '%' || Table1.property2 || '%');`